# How do test Firebase (for Android) push notification scalability

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have system that can send out push notifications to large number of mobile clients. We use Firebase for sending push notifications to Android mobile devices.

So have few questions:

- Is there any published data from firebase (google) team in terms of number of push notifications/sec it can receive?
- If I wanted to conduct an end-to-end scalability test. Is there anyway I can simulate N-number of devices registering with platform and get confirmation that device got the notification.  So I can measure end-to-end time it takes for system to deliver push notification, and also how many devices can we send notifications.
- Also open to hear about any "products" that may allow me to conduct this type of push notification performance tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*firebaser here*

tl;dr: please don't load test our infrastructure. At best (and most likely) it'll go completely unnoticed by our SRE team, but (if it *is* detected) it may get you blocked from further usage.

---

Firebase Cloud Messaging is used by most apps on most Android phones to deliver messages. It is used by the largest social network apps on your phone. It averages delivery of many millions of messages per second, and in a recent blog post [Delivering Messages at the scale of the World Cup](https://firebase.blog/posts/2023/05/cloud-messaging-world-cup-scale) we documented that it delivered 46M QPS during the world cup final in 2022, up from its average of 18M QPS.

At that scale the traffic from your app is likely to be negligible. Even if your app becomes very successful by your own metrics, FCM handles messages from *many* such apps in parallel and is built to handle the scale.

---

If you want to load test *your* part of the infrastructure for sending messages, I recommend setting up a mock server that handles the calls to FCM with simple response codes and then using the URL of that server for testing.

---

While Firebase does measure delivery latency and sometimes reports information on that in aggregate, there is no API available for you to access the data. If you want to measure the delivery latency, consider instrumenting your own server-side and client-side code to accomplish this.

Comment: "If you want to load test your part of the infrastructure for sending messages, I recommend setting up a mock server that handles the calls to FCM with simple response codes and then using the URL of that server for testing." That is what we want to do -- so we will mock the API calls to FCM. Also thank you for link to the blog post